# Text loads too big in small window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I'm working on a site that uses jquery to change the font size on any window resize, to keep everything in the right place. It works great, but when someones browser isn't maximized, the font still loads as if it is, until the user resizes their browser. Even if I make the browser smaller than it was on page load, the font will adjust. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mainwidth = $('.main').width();
    var mainheight = $('.main').height(mainwidth * .8895);
    var headerwidth = $('.header-middle').width();
    $('.main').height(mainwidth * .8895)
    $('.logo').width(headerwidth * .049);
    $('.logo').height(headerheight * .7533);
    $('.divider').width(headerwidth * .00204);
    $('.design-image').width(headerwidth * .2547);

    $('.call-us-today').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01836});
    $('.header-paragraph').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01734});
    $('.header-paragraph-footer').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01632});
    $('.top-text').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .02448});
    $('.graybar-text').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .03265});
    $('.body-header').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .02245});
    $('.body-text').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01632});
    $('.footer').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01224});
    $('.banner-text').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .02244});

    $('.graybar-text').css({'letter-spacing': headerwidth * .00408});


});

$(window).resize(function() {
    var mainwidth = $('.main').width();
    var mainheight = $('.main').height(mainwidth * .8895);
    var headerwidth = $('.header-middle').width();
    var headerheight = $('.header-middle').height();
    $('.main').height(mainwidth * .8895);
    $('.logo').width(headerwidth * .049);
    $('.logo').height(headerheight * .7533);
    $('.lady-image').width(headerwidth * .2835);
    $('.divider').width(headerwidth * .00204);
    $('.design-image').width(headerwidth * .2547);

    $('.call-us-today').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01836});
    $('.header-paragraph').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01734});
    $('.header-paragraph-footer').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01632});
    $('.top-text').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .02448});
    $('.graybar-text').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .03265});
    $('.body-header').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .02245});
    $('.body-text').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01632});
    $('.footer').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01224});
    $('.banner-text').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .02244});

    $('.graybar-text').css({'letter-spacing': headerwidth * .00408});
});
```

Does document.ready not load until after the pages loads? Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're doing this with jQuery instead of just media queries? That's a lot of extra JS for something that can be taken care of with just CSS.

Comment: It looks like the OP is going for much more responsively than typical media queries will provide. To do what the OP is showing, you'd need a media query breakpoint for every possible browser pixel width.

Comment: Alternatively, one of these jQuery plugins might be helpful: http://fittextjs.com/ or http://jbrewer.github.io/Responsive-Measure/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by changing your code very slightly. Simply take the

```
$(window).resize(function() {
```

bit and change it to

```
$(window).resize(resizeMyStuff)
```

and then make a new function using your existing code that you had inside the resize handler.

```
function resizeMyStuff() {
var mainwidth = $('.main').width();
var mainheight = $('.main').height(mainwidth * .8895);
var headerwidth = $('.header-middle').width();
var headerheight = ... etc
```

That way, you can call that function at the end of your $(document).ready function therefore setting the size every time the page loads.

You can also use

```
var browserWidth = $(window).width();
var browserHeight = $(window).height();
```

to pick up your window sizes from rather than relying on a page element (that could be under the influence of some weird css inheritance or something going on).